# How to return source view from IExceptionFilter.OnException()

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that calls an ASP.NET Core Web API for some data. The Web API can return a Bad Request response with model state errors and I want to automatically handle the bad request and display the model state errors coming from the web API in my MVC view.

I tried to write an Exception Filter to do this but I am unsure on how I can tell the exception filter to display the view that threw the exception.

```
public class WebApiExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            // My web API client will throw a WebApiException if it doesn't produce a successful response
            if (context.Exception is WebApiException webApiEx)
            {
                switch (webApiEx.StatusCode)
                {
                    case StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest:
                        context.ModelState.AddJsonModelErrors(webApiEx.Response); // This method de-serialises the model state from the web API response
                                                                                  // and adds it to the MVC model state
                        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I get the exception filter to return the view where the exception occurred so I can display the model errors? Or alternatively is there a better way to accomplish this? I don't want to have to try/catch every web API call I do in my MVC actions.

Answer (score 0):

For replacing view, you may try code beblow:

```
public class WebApiExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // My web API client will throw a WebApiException if it doesn't produce a successful response
        if (context.Exception is WebApiException webApiEx)
        {
            switch (webApiEx.StatusCode)
            {
                case StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest:
                    ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                        context.ModelState);
                    context.ModelState.AddJsonModelErrors(webApiEx.Response); // This method de-serialises the model state from the web API response
                                                                              // and adds it to the MVC model state
                    viewData.Model = new Product(); //replace it with your model from WebApiException
                    context.Result = new ViewResult() {
                        ViewName = "Create", //replace it with your real view from WebApiException
                        ViewData = viewData,
                    };

                    context.ExceptionHandled = true;
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this way, you need to configure the Model and ViewName.